# limit of variant form of incomplete Gamma function

Tags: limits

What is the limit of

$$\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}M\frac{(Mt)^Me^{-Mt}}{M!}$$

where $0<t<\infty$, $M\in\mathbb{N}$

It is supposed to be 0 by the data observed but i could not prove it theoretically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for $M!$ we get
$$
M\,\frac{(M\,t)^Me^{-Mt}}{M!}\sim\sqrt{\frac{M}{2\,\pi}}\,t^M\,e^{-Mt}.
$$